# Form controls are undefined

Tags: forms, angular

My form is made in the following way:

```html
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="register(form);">
    <div class="registerinput">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input #firstname="ngModel" type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" required ngModel>
        <div [hidden]="!form.controls.firstname.touched && !form.controls.firstname.errors?.required" class="alert-danger">
            Please enter your name
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!form.controls.firstname.touched && !form.controls.firstname.errors?.maxlength" class="alert-danger">
             Max length is 30 characters
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!form.controls.firstname.touched && !form.controls.firstname.errors?.pattern" class="alert-danger">
             Only letters are allowed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="registerinput">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-register">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/register/register.component.html:7:17 caused by: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined
Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/register/register.component.html:7:17 caused by: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined
```

It seems like it cannot find my controls. However, when I try to print out form.controls, I get the following result:

[image]

So in this case, it finds them just fine. What is the problem here? I've made something similar in the past that worked.

UPDATE: I found out that instead of for example `form.controls.firstname.touched`, I have to access them using just `firstname.touched`. I just don't understand why, because I have another file in the same project where I'm using forms which has been made in the exact same way, but in that one I was using `form.controls.*`. I guess you can use `firstname.touched` if you have declared a template reference variable, but I don't know under which circumstances you can use `form.controls.*`.

Comment: please provide the code for formGroup creation.

Comment: I don't have that. I didn't need it the last time I did this. I'm just sending the form to a method in my component which then handles everything.

Comment: Maybe `form.controls` isn’t yet initialized when you try to access it. `firstname` may be (in such case) already initialized, as you’re accessing it directly (not through `NgForm`).

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess too. If that is indeed the case, I just have no idea how to prevent the error.

Comment: Have you tried changing `! form.controls.(…)` to `! form.controls?.(…)`?

Comment: No, haven't tried that. I'll just be using the template reference variable from now on i think.

Comment: I tried what @gsc mentioned and it doesn't work. It seems when the form is initialized there is a small instant where the controls are undefined. After which you can access the controls just fine using the mentioned method: form.controls.firstname... Weird

Comment: I run into a similar problem which is giving me a headache. Is there no solution for that?

Comment: It will work if you write it like this `form.controls.firstname?.touched`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing validation is :

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="register(form);">
    <div class="registerinput">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input #firstname="ngModel" type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" required ngModel>
        <div [hidden]="!firstname.touched && !firstname.errors?.required" class="alert-danger">
            Please enter your name
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!firstname.touched && !firstname.errors?.maxlength" class="alert-danger">
             Max length is 30 characters
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!firstname.touched && !firstname.errors?.pattern" class="alert-danger">
             Only letters are allowed
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="registerinput">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-register" [disabled]='!form.valid'>Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This one is pretty simple and easy way of doing.

Comment: I can't see any difference except for the [disabled] part. Is that correct?

Comment: yes but in your code it was throwing error right ? , this will work exactly as you wanted and also minified the error checking code 
by 
!firstname.touched from !form.controls.firstname.touched

Comment: Although I would have liked to know why the controls are undefined on the initial load of the form, at least this let me get around the issue for now.